# Checking the result of a random action?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, skspritenode, skaction

```
var colorize1 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.3)

        var colorize2 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.greenColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.3)

        var colorize3 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.3)

        var actions = [colorize1, colorize2, colorize3]

        var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

        var action = actions[randomIndex]

        let seconds = 0.14
        let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
        let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {


            self.Ball.runAction(action)


        })

    }
```

So, this code colorizes my ball red, green, or blue. Is there a way to check which color it selected while my game is running? It doesn't just pick one and then it's done, the color of my ball changes every few seconds. How can I construct an if statement like: "If the random color picked by my action is red then print("hey") or something like that?

*edit* I am new to swift and xCode, so I might need more in-depth help.

Comment: Can't you just `switch` on the value of `randomIndex`?

Comment: @AMomchilov Could you show me an example?

Comment: I feel that you keep asking questions without _really_ informing us about what you are trying to accomplish. You ask about checking the color that is selected but then describes performing a random thing like printing a string... What values are you _actually_ after and _what_  do you need them for?

Comment: I'm trying to make my first app and have little experience with xCode. Here is what I need. I need my player to lose if he tries to enter a gap between two walls if the color of the walls and ball are different. @T.BenjaminLarsen I keep asking because I definitely can't figure it out and I'm trying to get useful help on how to do that.

Comment: I really don't mind helping, but you've asked a question regarding the same exact issue as you are now describing a few hours ago. I supplied an answer (that may or may not be helpful) but instead of keeping that discussion going you create a new thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just switch on your `randomIndex`:

```
switch randomIndex  {
case 0:
    print("colorize1")
case 1:
    print("colorize2")
case 2:
    print("colorize3")
}
```

Comment: @TiptonixBeats you should look into making `colorize1`, `colorize2`, `colorize3` into an enumeration.